# Why doesnt the .avi file not play rendered animation but blender does?

Tags: animation, video

So I just finished rendering a slow motion animation using the video sequence editor and at 500 samples. It took quite some time.. anyways... I went to the video file it exported and it shows 10 seconds but doesn’t play (it goes straight to the end). Blender however can play the rendered animation. Why would that be? Also is there someway I can re-export the animation after it has finished?

Comment: Your question seems related to a specific video player rather than Blender. If Blender can play it, the problem comes from whatever player you use.

Comment: Also it is a bad idea to render to video directly. Render as a sequence of images and encode later. That way you can try different settings without having to re-render